# Facing an issue when insert HTML into Webnode

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system

I am facing an issue when inserting an HTML into Webnode. Webnode is adding my script tag in div? how can I then run my JavaScript written in my script tag?

I insert HTML into Webnode but it places my script tag in a div how can I then run the script tag?
[attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJvAr.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.